# Graylog docker container only binds when it listens to 0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1?

Tags: docker, ip, graylog2

My docker graylog container has an input that listens to `127.0.0.1:1522`. I have port forwarded my machines `127.0.0.1:1522 -> 1522/tcp` of the docker host container. But I am not able to do `curl 127.0.0.1:1522`. Any idea whats happening? Moreover if I change the address to `0.0.0.0` for the listening of the input, it works : `curl 0.0.0.0:1522`. Please help.

Comment: what is your OS? Linux, Windows or Mac?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu OS

Comment: I think I got the problem: What I did was that I port forwarded docker-host port to container port, and hence not able to access that from my machine local host, but then how do I port forward from my machine to docker host ?